# can't add fields in friend's dynamodb using lambda

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-iam

I've tried to set up an API gateway and IAM permission but I keep getting an error message when I test my lambda function.

```
"errorType": "Runtime.UserCodeSyntaxError",
"errorMessage": "SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module",
"trace": 
"Runtime.UserCodeSyntaxError: SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module",

"    at _loadUserApp (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:98:13)",
"    at Object.module.exports.load (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:140:17)",
"    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/index.js:43:30)",
"    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1138:30)",
"    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:10)",
"    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:986:32)",
"    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:14)",
"    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)",
"    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47"
```

My lambda function:

```
import * as AWS from 'aws-sdk';

AWS.config.update({
   accessKeyId: 'key',
   secretAccessKey: 'key',
   region: 'us-east-1'
});

const documentClient: AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

interface IEvent {
    email: string;
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
}

exports.handler = async (event: IEvent): Promise<void> => {
    if (!event.email) {
        throw new Error('Candidate email is required.');
    }
    if (!event.firstName) {
        throw new Error('Candidate first name is required.');
    }
    if (!event.lastName) {
        throw new Error('Candidate last name is required.');
    }

    await documentClient.put({
        TableName: 'honeypot-interview-contacts',
        Item: event
    }).promise();
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You've got the error right there, actually: `SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`. Try switching to `require`? And it looks like you're running TypeScript? I don't think the default Node runtime has built in support for TS, you might want to run the code through the TS compiler first, that should also handle the import error.

Comment: Yes, the code is running TypeScript. I've changed to **const AWS = require('aws-sdk');** However, I'm still having at [Interface IEvent]. I get new error saying: "errorMessage": "SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier"

Comment: Yeah, the Node runtime on Lambda can't run Typescript directly... you'll need to either compile it first or use only regular Javascript.